# Add Letter to Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to create an array that empty and no size.

```
char[] enteredLettersArray = {};
```

That array stores letter I entered from keyboard.
for example:
I enter letters again and again until I find a correct letter, I want to store the letters all I entered.
How can I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindTryC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner keybInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        char secretLetter = 'C';
        char[] enteredLettersArray = {};

        
        System.out.print("Please Enter a Letter : ");
        char enteredLetter = keybInput.next().charAt(0);
        // ? ? ? ? ? ?;
        while (secretLetter != enteredLetter) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter a Letter : ");
            enteredLetter = keybInput.next().charAt(0);
            // ? ? ? ? ? ?;
        }

        System.out.println(enteredLettersArray.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enteredLettersArray))    ;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is of fixed length so if you create as empty it will remain empty.  What you want is a collection that can resize.  The standard replacement for an array is a List and the preferred implementation is usually ArrayList.

```
List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, looking at what you are trying to do you may prefer a Set.  The HashSet is the typical choice.

```
Set<Character> letters = new HashSet<>();
```

In either case, you will have a Collection that can resize as you add things to it.

Answer (score 0):

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

This is what mentioned in official [Java tutorial page.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). So you have to create array & initialize with some size.

If you want to use dynamic data-structure , consider using `List<Character>` so that you don't need to define size while creating object of list.

Answer (score 0):

````
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FindTryC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner keybInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        char secretLetter = 'C';
        char[] enteredLettersArray = {};

        
        System.out.print("Please Enter a Letter : ");
        char enteredLetter = keybInput.next().charAt(0);
        // ? ? ? ? ? ?;
int i = 0;
        while (secretLetter != enteredLetter) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter a Letter : ");
            enteredLettersArray[i]= keybInput.next();
            i++;
            
        }

        System.out.println(enteredLettersArray.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enteredLettersArray));
    enter code here
    }

}```
````